# Excel: Using text functions to find the middle

Tags: excel, string, text

I want to extract `Moss` `Ariel` and `Murphy` from the following strings using text functions in Excel.

```
Gabriela Moss669.11695-5000-53420000000-1232
Connie Ariel1025.11695-2004-51490000000-1231
Kelly Murphy1040.58695-2200-50630000000-1235
```

I have a basic grasp with using text functions, but this one has stumped me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I need to make a formula such that it requires no changes copying it down the list of records.

Comment: Can you give few more examples, or are there always 3 digits before the dot? You can use the `FIND` Excel function to find the position of the space and dot and then the `MID` Excel function

Comment: @Slai added more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier and shorter in Google Sheets or with VBA UDF, but here is another array formula solution (enter it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) from https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-and-numbers

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,MIN(FIND(ROW($1:$10)-1,A1&"0123456789"))-FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

This might work without array formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"."},A1))-FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Comment: What exactly is ROW doing in this formula?

Comment: @JonathanRauscher it's just a shorter way to generate the `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` array like in the linked example.

Answer (score 1):

Say you data begins in A1

[image]

First extract the full name with the following formula

```
[B1] = {LEFT(A1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1)),0)-1)}
```

This is an array formula, press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after typing formula in B1. Then fill down the formula to the rest of the rows.

Next, simply extract the last name from the full name

```
[C1] = RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH(" ",B1))
```

---

If you prefer to do it in-one-go here is the formula

```
[B1] = {MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1)),0)-1-SEARCH(" ",A1))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below formula as it is, no need for array formula to achieve this.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1)+1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))-SEARCH(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Comment: this is exactly what slai's answer is

Comment: I see your point, but when I pasted this answer that part was not there in slai's post and not sure when that was added. I could see there was a edit.

Answer (score -1):

You need to combine the functions `instr` and `mid`. `instr` returns the index in a string of the first appearance of a sub-string (or a single character). `mid` returns a sub-string starting at a given position and with a length of the extracted sub-string. In your case, something like:

```
 MID(MyString,Index(MyString,"Moss"),Len("Moss"))
```

where `MyString` holds your source string.